# Dropdown / close block

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

On this in my application there is a filter button, when clicked, the user can see a list (done using a modal window) of categories for filtering (Categories are: Method, Status code, Link, Date).

However, I would like all categories (Method, Status code, Link, Date) to be collapsed and expanded.

My code is divided into blocks (for each filter category there is a separate file).
Here I will give an example of how I built the filtering by Method.
And I will be grateful if you tell me how to change it in such a way that this category could open and close (for the rest of the categories I will do it myself)

```
export default function FilterMethod  () {
const [methods, setMethods] = useState([]);

const onMethodChange = (e) => {
    let selectedMethods = [...methods];

    if (e.checked)
        selectedMethods.push(e.value);
    else
        selectedMethods.splice(selectedMethods.indexOf(e.value), 1);

    setMethods(selectedMethods);
}

return (
        <div>
            <h6>Method</h6>
            <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                <Checkbox inputId="method1" name="method" value="Connect" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Connect') !== -1} />
                <label  htmlFor="method1">Connect</label>
            </div>

            <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                <Checkbox inputId="method2" name="method" value="Delete" onChange={onMethodChange} checked={methods.indexOf('Delete') !== -1} />
                <label htmlFor="method2">Delete</label>
            </div>

         // Here I shortened the code, since it's just a list of methods

        </div>

)}
```

.css file

```
    input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this change in your component will help?
I just added a local state `isExpanded` to flag the expand/collapse state, and it should render to different versions of the component accordingly

```
export default function FilterMethod() {
  const [methods, setMethods] = useState([]);
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  const toggleExpand = () => {
    setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
  };

  const onMethodChange = (e) => {
    let selectedMethods = [...methods];

    if (e.checked) selectedMethods.push(e.value);
    else selectedMethods.splice(selectedMethods.indexOf(e.value), 1);

    setMethods(selectedMethods);
  };

  return isExpanded ? (
    <div>
      <h6>Method</h6>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Checkbox
          inputId="method1"
          name="method"
          value="Connect"
          onChange={onMethodChange}
          checked={methods.indexOf("Connect") !== -1}
        />
        <label htmlFor="method1">Connect</label>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Checkbox
          inputId="method2"
          name="method"
          value="Delete"
          onChange={onMethodChange}
          checked={methods.indexOf("Delete") !== -1}
        />
        <label htmlFor="method2">Delete</label>
      </div>
      // Here I shortened the code, since it's just a list of methods
      <div onClick={toggleExpand}>Click me to collapse</div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div onClick={toggleExpand}>Click me to expand</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response, but for some reason I get just a white screen (no result)

Comment: do you have console error ?